# Deserialize echonest JSON response

Tags: json, vb.net

I try to deserialize a JSON response from the echonest project. http://the.echonest.com/

I did read in the response in a string which looked like this:

```
{  
   "response":{  
      "status":{  
         "version":"4.2",
         "code":0,
         "message":"Success"
      },
      "songs":[  
         {  
            "tag":0,
            "error":"need codes in query for fingerprint matching"
         },
         {  
            "tag":2,
            "score":32,
            "title":"Guilty Filthy Soul",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARILGMH1447548D699",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATIONMSDeluxeEdition.jpg",
            "id":"SOJIPHL12BF395951C"
         },
         {  
            "tag":1,
            "score":39,
            "title":"Soul Wars",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOJHHWN130516E1917"
         },
         {  
            "tag":3,
            "score":46,
            "title":"MF",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SODOMSN1360091E842"
         },
         {  
            "tag":12,
            "score":41,
            "title":"Swinging From The Castles",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SONTNCN1425843249E"
         },
         {  
            "tag":15,
            "score":36,
            "title":"Shoestrings",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARILGMH1447548D699",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATIONMSDeluxeEdition.jpg",
            "id":"SOLLDKR142585BFA69"
         },
         {  
            "tag":10,
            "score":28,
            "title":"Not Your Fault (Robert DeLong Remix)",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SORWXAJ1421C6F8E56"
         },
         {  
            "tag":4,
            "score":43,
            "title":"Some Kind of Joke",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SOSFVGK142586E007F"
         },
         {  
            "tag":9,
            "score":37,
            "title":"Sail (Borgore Pop The Sweating I'm Sailing Remix)",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SOWQQUP14258815CCA"
         },
         {  
            "tag":21,
            "score":56,
            "title":"Sail - Tde Remix Featuring Kendrick Lamar & Ab Soul",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SODVLLQ13F68EE4DB0"
         },
         {  
            "tag":20,
            "score":73,
            "title":"Wake Up",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOJYTIP130516E077F"
         },
         {  
            "tag":18,
            "score":61,
            "title":"Sail - Dan The Automator Remix",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOYJPEA1393D0A8275"
         },
         {  
            "tag":8,
            "score":71,
            "title":"All I Need",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOCTVVU1315CD5159E"
         },
         {  
            "tag":16,
            "score":45,
            "title":"Kill Your Heroes",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOSHUZU1315CD51CC6"
         },
         {  
            "tag":23,
            "score":40,
            "title":"Burn It Down - Innerpartysystem Remix",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOWBQBY12D9F5212E2"
         },
         {  
            "tag":24,
            "score":35,
            "title":"Megalithic Symphony",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOLYFXI1315CD50F08"
         },
         {  
            "tag":17,
            "score":21,
            "title":"Soul Wars - Live in Salzburg, Austria",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SORXTYU142587B6D9B"
         },
         {  
            "tag":14,
            "score":64,
            "title":"Everybody’s Got A Secret",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SOJBTCM13AA5063525"
         },
         {  
            "tag":26,
            "score":70,
            "title":"People",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SOGPZIH1425829F571"
         },
         {  
            "tag":5,
            "score":71,
            "title":"Sail",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SOIBWQG131634AC357"
         },
         {  
            "tag":25,
            "score":62,
            "title":"Sail (Unlimited Gravity Remix)",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOTEBOO1393CF870D4"
         },
         {  
            "tag":27,
            "score":41,
            "title":"Burn It Down",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOZAEHP131634ABE40"
         },
         {  
            "tag":6,
            "score":40,
            "title":"Jump On My Shoulders",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOEQIJG1315CD51AE8"
         },
         {  
            "tag":29,
            "score":33,
            "title":"I've Been Dreaming",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOUEMDH13E96158B43"
         },
         {  
            "tag":19,
            "score":33,
            "title":"Thiskidsnotalright",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOYHQBE13EBDBB87B0"
         },
         {  
            "tag":22,
            "score":72,
            "title":"Guilty Filthy Soul (feat. Walé) - Samantha Ronson Remix",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOFZULB1338A5D71A3"
         },
         {  
            "tag":30,
            "score":47,
            "title":"People",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SOEHJMA1315CD517AF"
         },
         {  
            "tag":31,
            "score":42,
            "title":"Jump On My Shoulders (Thomas From Ghostland Observatory Remix)",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"Awolnation",
            "id":"SOVIGND142582A368B"
         },
         {  
            "tag":7,
            "score":8,
            "title":"Some Sort of Creature",
            "message":"OK (match type 6)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOCGVUY13670F53A9C"
         },
         {  
            "tag":11,
            "score":103,
            "title":"Knights of Shame",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOIYLVA140C222E546"
         },
         {  
            "tag":28,
            "score":81,
            "title":"Not Your Fault",
            "message":"OK (match type 5)",
            "artist_id":"ARJVYUI12AA0D8C20C",
            "artist_name":"AWOLNATION",
            "id":"SOIZFJM1315CD537B0"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to "dig" through this response via "ForEach". It would be awesome if i just got presented each song as an item in a listview or an other easy to handle object with the following keys:

```
    Dim lvResponse As ListView
    lvResponse = New ListView
    lvResponse.Columns.Add("Index")
    lvResponse.Columns.Add("Score")
    lvResponse.Columns.Add("Title")
    lvResponse.Columns.Add("Message")
    lvResponse.Columns.Add("ArtistID")
    lvResponse.Columns.Add("Artist")
    lvResponse.Columns.Add("ID")
```

But i'm getting stuck. I can only display all items within the debugger if i put the JSON string into a dictionary like this:

```
Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(JSON)
```

As i'm a beginner i do not know how to handle a dictionary nor i know C#. So answers in pure VB.net would be really helpful.

As Plutonix did state this JSON is a "complex Object"-> When i try to ask the debugger of the dict.item i got the following:

```
(New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView(Of String, Object)((New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView(Of String, Object)(dict)).Items(0).Value)).Items(0)
```

And the second:

```
(New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView(Of String, Object)((New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView(Of String, Object)(dict)).Items(0).Value)).Items(1)
```

In the Second one i got:

```
(New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView(Of String, Object)((New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView(Of String, Object)(dict)).Items(0).Value)).Items(1)
```

and under there finally is an arraylist with 31 items. (Of course valid for this sample only):

The complexity of this is my problem - i don't know how parse this via ForEach.

Comment: The JSON doesnt look like a Dictionary, but a more [complex object](http://developer.echonest.com/raw_tutorials/getting_data.html).

Comment: Don't you think you may delete (or at least show just what matters) of all of that JSON you've got there? This is the largest question I've ever seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got an answer! Credits goes to a guy (Diablo2000) in an other forum!

Solution:
 First create some classes that represent the objects in the JSON:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property response() As Response
End Class

Public Class Response
    Public Property status() As Status
    Public Property songs() As Song()
End Class

Public Class Status
    Public Property version() As String
    Public Property code() As Integer
    Public Property message() As String
End Class

Public Class Song
    Public Property tag() As Integer
    Public Property [error]() As String
    Public Property score() As Integer
    Public Property title() As String
    Public Property message() As String
    Public Property artist_id() As String
    Public Property artist_name() As String
    Public Property id() As String
End Class


Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Dim rootObject As Rootobject = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Rootobject)(json)
```

And finally just walk trough ...

```
If (rootObject.response.status.code = 0) Then
            For Each song As Song In rootObject.response.songs
                Console.WriteLine(song.title)
            Next
        End If
```